# Expectation of the function of multiple random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am working through some basic probability stuff and have a question regarding functions of multiple variables. If I have two random variables $X,Y$ which have some joint probability distribution $P_{XY}(x,y)$ I can obtain expected value of some function $f(x,y)$ by integrating across both variables:
$$
E[f(x,y)] = \int \int f(x,y) P_{XY}(x,y) \ dx \ dy
$$

we can also obtain the expected value of a function of a single variable by following the workings [here](https://yiboyang.com/posts/2016/Jun/11/joint-vs-marginal-expectation/)
$$
E[g(x)] = \int g(x) P_{X}(x) \ dx
$$

If the integration across a function of a single value has meaning I am wondering how we would interpret the integration of a function of multiple variables across a single value
$$
\int f(x,y) P_X(x)dx
$$

and wether this expression has any meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last expression gives you the expectation of $f(X,y)$ where $X$ denotes the random variable and $y$ is fixed.

So defining $Z_y:=f(X,y)$ it gives the expectation of random variable $Z_y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Am i right in thinking that in this case $E[Z_y]$ would be the expectation given a particular value of y and therefore still dependent on the joint distribution?

Comment: There is only dependence wrt the original joint distribution in the sense that the distribution of $X$ is deduced from the joint distribution. That's all. The calculation of $\mathbb EZ_y$ does not depend on some condition $Y=y$ as you seem to think.

Comment: $\mathbb Ef(X,y)$ and $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)\mid Y=y]$ are essentially different. If e.g. $X=Y$ then $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)\mid Y=y]=f(y,y)$, but $\mathbb Ef(X,y)$ is calculated on base of the distribution of $X$ and the equality $X=Y$ plays no part in that.